# Zend framework Specifying Module Controller Directories implementation?

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, directory

I am trying to create a Modular structure to zend framework project, what i am trying to do is create a module which will look something like this

```
docroot/
    index.php
application/
    default/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
            FooController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
                foo/
            helpers/
            filters/
    blog/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
            helpers/
            filters/
    news/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
            ListController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
                list/
            helpers/
            filters/
```

what i cant understand after reading the documentation is where to add the following code or should i refactore the /zendlibrary/Controller/front.php ?

```
$front->setControllerDirectory(array(
    'default' => '/path/to/application/controllers',
    'blog'    => '/path/to/application/blog/controllers'
));
```

OR

```
$front->addControllerDirectory('/path/to/application/news/controllers',
                               'news');
```

Comment: The solution is somewhat different. We've done this but I don't have the time to dredge up the code. Much of it resides in the configuration.

Comment: One question, Is it wise to put your application code below your docroot, shouldn't it be above your docroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a method to your bootstrap is probably the easiest way:

```
protected function _initFrontController()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->setControllerDirectory(array(
        'default' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/default/controllers',
        'blog'    => APPLICATION_PATH.'/blog/controllers'
    ));

    return $front;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when we did this we put modules in **application/modules/** instead of application/

In configuration (application/configs/configuration.ini), you'll need something like this:

```
[bootstrap]

Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Zend_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "default_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "blog_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "news_"


resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = 1
resources.frontController.throwErrors = true

resources.modules[] = "default"
resources.modules[] = "blog"
resources.modules[] = "news"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"

resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "modules/default/views/"
```

There might be some more to it, let me know if this helps.

Comment: no it will still hit on the module default when i ask for the controller of the admin so what i want to do it when i put localhost/Admin/index it will go to that directory not just ignore the directory and giving an error that the controller admin is not there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Zend Tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html)?

It's easy as this:

```
zf create module mymodule
```

Read more on Akrabat's post [Bootstrapping modules in ZF](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/bootstrapping-modules-in-zf-1-8/).

You can easily create controllers, actions, models, forms within the module using the command line. The tool will generate everything for you.